# NodeJS app from client machine cant connect to mysql server on same LAN

Tags: mysql, node.js, tomcat

I have two machines 1,2 on same LAN. machine1 is running an application say app1 developed in nodejs, mysql server and tomcat. from machine 2 if i try to access app1, i get connection refused message.

[image: app1 throw error from machine 2]

however, everything works fine on machine1, with localhost alias or with ip. I tried to debug fetch requests but node server on machine1 does not get any request at all. i disabled win10 firewall but still no luck. I spent a day on googling it and tried all possible solutions that worked before.

[image: from app1 on machine2, no call rcvd on node server on machine1]

i created a sample app in nodejs from machine2 to test connection, and it gets connected. i checked all routes to see if webserver (tomcat) is ok, then i tried node http-server, there is no issue in terms of navigation
[image: machine2 connection ok][image: node on machine2 connects with sql server on machine1]

Comment: It is unclear from your question if it is the mysql connectiin that fails or you cannot even connect to the app via http remotely

Comment: i think issue is with tomcat mysql connectivity, i tried installing mysql j connector and updating server.xml nothing works. however, i was able to get data from postman from other machines. this means mysql and express connectivity is ok. so something wrong with tomcat. any other webserver to try?

Comment: i created node http server and result is same, it works on localhost but not on anyother machine on network and irony is postmaster can process those calls at both node http server and tomcat server ports

Answer (score 0):

on client machines javascripts are downloaded before execution therefore client machine resolves localhost to its own ip. so i used localstorage for server path in my fetch calls.

```
fetch("http://"+server+":"+port+"/emp/getAll")
```